# prismic - How to qgl select based on length or NOT NULL

Tags: graphql, gql, prismic.io

Since prismic has no concept of required fields, we might end up with null instead of data.

I am looking for a way to pull prismic data in gatsby app, filtering out unwanted entities.

**the SQL idea**

```
SELECT *
FROM allPrismicAnnouncement
WHERE quote IS NOT NULL;
```

**actual gql i use**

```
export const query = graphql`
query AnnouncementCardQuery {
 allPrismicAnnouncement(sort: {order: DESC, fields: data___date}) {
  edges {
   node {
   uid
    id
     data {
      quote {
        text
       }
      subtitle1 {
     text
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
`
```

how to use **filter**, **include** or similar approach to filter out filtering out articles with **no quote**.
Option 2 -  ignore all quotes with length < 100 chars

Answer (score 0):

This question has answers on [prismic community forum](https://community.prismic.io/t/filtering-out-unfilled-fields-with-gatsby-graphql-gatsby-source-prismic/4323)

> Yes, you can use the ne [operator](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/graphql-reference/#complete-list-of-possible-operators); to filter the response with [Prismic fields](https://prismic.io/docs/technologies/arguments-filter-sort-limit-skip-gatsby#filter-using-prismic-fields).

I'm using `allPrismicBlogpost` and have a similar query and problem. I think something like this would work for you (changed sort to [`first_publication_date`](https://prismic.io/docs/technologies/order-your-results-graphql#first-publication-date)).

```js
export const query = graphql`
query AnnouncementCardQuery {
 allPrismicAnnouncement(filter: {data: {quote: {text: {ne: null}}}}, sort: { order: DESC, fields: first_publication_date}) {
  edges {
   node {
   uid
    id
     data {
      quote {
        text
       }
      subtitle1 {
     text
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
`
```